# Git See Files/Code Changed after Merge

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atom-editor

When using Git, I can see the code that was changed between each commit from the GitHub or BitBucket interface (green for lines added and red for lines deleted).

How can I do that using Atom.io without going to the GitHub/BitBucket web interface?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the [git-diff](https://github.com/atom/git-diff) extension  colorizes the gutter next to lines that have been added, edited, and removed.

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/671378/2241519/04791a24-9cd6-11e3-9a12-164cabe81d58.png]

Comment: I was trying this extension, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I think because the commit has already happened. How can I travel "back" in time and see the differences that happened in each commit?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Git history in Atom, you might give these packages a try:

- https://atom.io/packages/git-history - allows you to diff between versions of the selected file
- https://atom.io/packages/git-log - shows the Git history as a tree, similar to something like SourceTree

I also find the Open-in packages (https://atom.io/packages/open-in) useful, it allows to open the current file or project in an application of your choice, e.g. SourceTree. I use that when I want dive deeper into the Git history of a file...